# Wrong colors when converting an AVFrame to QVideoFrame

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I read videos with libav and display them in a QAbstractVideoSurface in QML. It works so far, however, I did not manage to get the colors right.

My av_read_frame Loop looks like this:

```
if (frameFinished)
{
                        SwsContext* context = nullptr;
                        context = sws_getContext(_frame->width, _frame->height, (AVPixelFormat)_frame->format, _frame->width, _frame->height, AVPixelFormat::AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA, SWS_BICUBIC, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
                        QImage img(_frame->width, _frame->height, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
                        uint8_t* dstSlice[] = { img.bits() };
                        int dstStride = img.width() * 4;
                        sws_scale(context, _frame->data, _frame->linesize,
                            0, _frame->height, dstSlice, &dstStride);

                        av_packet_unref(&packet);
                        sws_freeContext(context);
}
```

If I save the image to disk at this point, the colors are already wrong (everything looks red).
Later, I display the images in a video surface with the format QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32, and the colors are wrong again, but look different than the saved image (everything looks blue).

I started to experiment with libav/ffmpeg recently, so maybe the problem is something else and I just have no clue. Let me know, if you need more information :)

Comment: You have to get the order of the color channels right.  RGBA != ARGB != BGRA etc.

Comment: But do you see an error so far? I mean, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA and QImage::Format_RGBA8888 shoud match? There might be more pitfalls when converting to QVideoFrame, but when saving the image right now, it should have the correct colors, and it does not. I already tried different pixel formats, but did not manage to get the right colors. But I´ll try again, I also have no other idea so far.

Comment: Yes, they should match.  I had noticed this pitch of your question only after commenting.  What architecture are you on?  Because the docs for [QImage::Format_RGBA8888] (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum) say, it is architecture dependent.  Maybe you should go with QImage::Format_ARGB32 (and the corresponding ffmpeg-pixfmt).  Actually, from how the colors go wrong you could tell, which way the color channels took.

Comment: I was wrong, when saving the image at this point, it IS correct. Sorry for confusion, I messed up different tests. When I convert it to Format_ARGB32 before putting it into the QVideoFrame, everything is fine. So it depends on the endianess indeed, thanks. Have to find the "optimal" formats yet.